# PHP MongoDB fatal error: Read timed out

Tags: php-mongodb

sometimes there is a bug (~30%):

> Failed to connect to: IP:2333: Read timed out after reading 0 bytes,
>   waited for 0.000000 seconds

- Web server   Apache/2.2.16
- PHP version  PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze15
- PHP extension    mongo/1.4.0
- MongoDB version  2.2.3

In all cases. What is this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same bug. The solution is to set a timeout for your requests.

- You can do a `$cursor->timeout(-1);` on each of your cursors.
- Or simply add `MongoCursor::$timeout = -1;` in your index/connection file.

-1 is to set an infinite timeout. You can also put a value in milliseconds if you don't want infinite.